# Rspec mock_model not available in instanced object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have this code in a model called Project. It sets a owner to a project before the project is saved.

```
before_save :set_owner

# Set the owner of the project right before it is saved.
def set_owner
  self.owner_id = mock_model(User).id # current_user.id is stubbed out for a mock_model.
  # Lifecycle is set by the form's collection_select
end
```

And current_user function is stubbed out in my Rspec tests to return a mock_model (which is why the code above is showing mock_model instead of current_user).

Now, when I run this, my Rspec tests break, and complains:

```
undefined method `mock_model' for #<Project:0x105c70af0>
```

My guess, is that since before_save is a instance function, it somehow thinks that mock_model is a function defined in Project.

Someone must have encountered this before... Any way around it?

Comment: Addition to my comment: my helper methods in my controller cannot be used in my before_save function in my model? Even when I call current_user, it's giving me a error saying that undefined local variable or function current_user in <Project 0xA123B1>. The scope of the model doesn't include the helper methods in my application controller huh?

Answer (score 2):

Two things immediately stand out:

1. You shouldn't be using mock_model in your actual Project model. All test code should remain in the specs.
2. You cannot pass the current_user object from the controller to the model (at least not in any way you should).

I would use an attr_accessor in your project model to set the current_user id.

```
class Project < AR::Base
  attr_accessor :current_user

  def set_owner
    self.owner_id = current_user.id unless current_user.nil?
  end
end
```

Then your spec should look something more along the lines of:

```
it "should set the owner id" do
  user = mock_model(User)
  project = Project.new
  project.current_user = user
  project.save
  project.owner_id.should == user.id
end
```

Comment: I'm not using mock_model in my actual Project model. I just wrote that there to avoid confusion (basically that's what my tests replace the ACTUAL code with).   attr_accessor doesn't allow me to use a helper method though. My question is, how WOULD I get the actual current_user?

Comment: I'm a little confused, where are you trying to get the current user from? Your original question seemed to be asking why you got an undefined method mock_model in your Project model.

Comment: Sorry, my question has been unclear. current_user is a helper function defined in my application controller. So there are actually two issues. First one is that mock_model is NOT accessible from inside my before_save callback. The second one is that current_user is NOT accessible from inside my model. These two are linked by the fact that current_user is stubbed out in my tests to call mock_model. So if I get mock_model to work in my tests, current_user will not work in the implementation. Does that make more sense?

Comment: You can't use mock_model from inside the class you're testing. That is a fundamental error -- in other words, you're Doing It Wrong®.

`current_user` is not available in your model due to the separation of concerns of the Model-View-Controller pattern. Beerlington's answer allows you to pass in the value of `current_user` from the controller (or from the spec, as shown), so that you can set up Project correctly. This is the only feasible way to accomplish what you are trying to do. So give it a try, I think you'll find it works :)